# How to Draw a Rockwell RSLogix 5000 Ladder Logic Diagram with this Windows Forms Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, plc, ladder-logic

I found this `CLadderView` WinForms control that looks useful for drawing PLC ladder logic diagrams but I'm not too familiar with the `System.Drawing` namespace for `Graphics` or how to assign the control properly so it renders. The `CLadderView` should be able to take an L5X file from RSLogix 5000 and create a ladder logic diagram.

Here is the code I have so far:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var g = CreateGraphics();
        //var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        var ladderView = new CLadderView();
        ladderView.SetUserXMLFile("CarWash.L5X");
        ladderView.Width = Width;
        ladderView.Height = Height;
        ladderView.AutoSize = true;
        ladderView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(ladderView);
    }
}
```

**But it gives an empty screen:** [Empty Windows Forms GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMrNv.png)

**The CLadderView Control (it was too big for the post):** https://pastebin.com/fxn4jnWU

I tried various ways of connecting the `CLadderView` control to the root Win Forms window but nothing seems to work and it always comes back blank.

Comment: After assigning the xml data to draw you may need to ladderView.Invalidate(). Maybe a little later than the form load..

Comment: I tried calling invalidate but it didn't do anything. It seems like maybe I don't have the ladder view connected to the WinForm proprely.

Comment: Have you tried setting both the _Location_ and _Size_ properties?

Comment: Well, the class does inhrit the control onpaint event, so Invalidate should force it to redraw. Try putting it in a button click for testing to see if it is a timing issue!

Comment: Have you uploaded the InstructionElementsClass anywhere?  The code in paste bin does not work without it.  Please leave a note, if you get a chance to upload the rest of the project.